# How do you set a precise location?

Tags: 18.10, location, geolocation

I have enabled location services. I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 on a desktop that doesn't have a GPS. On Windows 10, I was able to set the location manually with an address.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to manually create the configuration directory as it's moved in this version, though falling back in case the directory does not exist:

```
mkdir ~/.config/redshift
```

Use your favorite text editor to create and edit the config file, I will use VS Code here:

```
code ~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf
```

Example config file heavily commented.

```
; Global settings
[redshift]

; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue2', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values.
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=manual

; this has changed since this version in favor of randr
; formerly vidmode has been mostly used from what I read
adjustment-method=randr

; Disable the smooth fade between temperatures when Redshift starts and stops.
; 0 will cause an immediate change between screen temperatures.
; 1 will gradually apply the new screen temperature over a couple of seconds.
fade=0

; Solar elevation thresholds.
; By default, Redshift will use the current elevation of the sun to determine
; whether it is daytime, night or in transition (dawn/dusk). When the sun is
; above the degrees specified with elevation-high it is considered daytime and
; below elevation-low it is considered night.
;elevation-high=3
;elevation-low=-6

; Custom dawn/dusk intervals.
; Instead of using the solar elevation, the time intervals of dawn and dusk
; can be specified manually. The times must be specified as HH:MM in 24-hour
; format.
;dawn-time=6:00-7:45
;dusk-time=18:35-20:15


; The location provider and adjustment method settings
; are in their own sections.
; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings.
; ex: 'redshift -l manual:help'
; Keep in mind that longitudes west of Greenwich (e.g. the Americas)
; are negative numbers.
[manual]
lat=00.8
lon=00.1

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings.
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust only screen 0.
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the first screen.
; If this option is not specified, Redshift will try to adjust _all_ screens.
[randr]
screen=0
```

This will Work for the Location. Update the location manually

```
[manual]
lat=00.8
lon=00.1
```

Comment: If you connect through Wi-Fi, I don't know if this is the case, it's generaly easier to see one's own location, there is nothing to configurate. Just type https://whatismyipaddress.com/ in your browser to check.

Comment: @DominikCornice - This is open issue. Check the Link for your reference.  https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/699

Comment: I'm a little confused why this answer mentions RedShift. OP just wants to set their location in Ubuntu's "Location Services". RedShift was never mentioned, and I highly doubt updating the location stored in RedShift, will have any effect on Ubuntu's internal location settings. Not to mention, this answer assumes users have RedShift already installed.